# Arch Linux ARM on RPi 2B, Xorg not Displaying Anything

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, raspberry-pi, display

I am trying to run Arch Linux ARM on my Raspberry Pi 2B and running into some issues with displaying anything with Xorg. I have the `xf86-video-fbdev` driver installed, which is what I have seen suggested in many other posts. I did try configuring a `.xinitrc` to run just a window manager, as well as installing and enabling sddm. Both produced the same result of just showing a black screen on startup.

I've also seen in other posts that using the `xf86-video-fbturbo-git` driver is recommended, but this no longer seems to be an option in the `alarm` repo, so I'm not sure how I would go about installing that.

What might be the issue here?

Comment: Please add more details about your configuration and the steps you tried so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those that are having a similar issue, I ended up finding a solution that works for me. My solution was to create a file at `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-driver.conf` with the following contents.

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "card0"
    Driver "fbdev"
    VendorName "All"
    BoardName "All"
EndSection
```

This will force Xorg to choose the fbdev driver to be used on graphics card 0 (which seems to be the default). After creating this file, a reboot displayed graphics!